# Update a table while reading it

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a database table with a Y/N flag in one column. I want to read all records where the flag is 'N' and after processing a record, set the flag to 'Y' in that record. Is it correct, and reasonable, to do this at the same time, using two separate connections? Or should I read the entire table first and update only after I'm done with the reading? What's the correct approach to this?

The database involved is Netezza, in case it matters.

Comment: It always matters. Since I don't know of netezza I cannot answer. But if it had been SQLite and WAL mode off, the answer would have been: no concurrent read and writes.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly seems cleaner to separate reading and writing. I just wondered if transaction isolation would help me here and whether there's a standard pattern to do that sort of thing.

Comment: did you [read this](http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?t=125306&view=previous)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read first then update.  Not asynchronsly.  If the "select" part takes a long time, you should consider doing it batches.  You can use a separate connections but should be confident you've completed your read.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly seems like the route of caution.  I was hoping to learn a little more about transaction isolation and other tools that databases might have available for that sort of thing.  But I agree that reading everything first and then updating is the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Depends mostly on your design and needs.

How important is the flag? What if something goes wrong when you have set all flags before you have processed them... and so on.

Why you need two connections is out of my understanding, usually you have one connection you keep open. I don't know the blocks of Netezza but some system can also be made to do select and update at the same time.

You could do:

1. Load a bunch, process them and then update all flags. (fastest, one fail = all fail)
2. Load a bunch, process one, update one flag, process next.. (quite fast and one fail don't hit em all)
3. Fetch and update them one by one. (will be slowest but most secure)